# why does the delphi ide increase the windows platform timer resolution?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

I have noticed that my battery life is significantly worse on my laptop whenever I have the delphi 2010 ide open. When I powercfg /energy trace, it shows (among other things) that bds.exe has requested a smaller timer resolution than the default of 15.6ms.

```
Current Timer Resolution (100ns units) 10006 
Maximum Timer Period (100ns units) 156250 


Requested Period 10000 
Requesting Process ID 7996 
Requesting Process Path \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin\bds.exe
```

Does delphi have a good reason to alter the platform timer resolution? Also do the latest versions of the ide have the same behavior?

Comment: I am not seeing that with XE7. I can't really see how it's an issue with a 5 year old version of the software unless you mean that applications developed with the IDE are exhibiting the same behavior. The problem with something like Delphi is that it could be done by a third party control. It's not necessarily the IDE that is changing things.

Comment: @Graymatter I am seeing this for XE7.  Firefox also requests 1ms, I noticed.  I expect the reason is to make `Sleep` ms accurate.

Comment: @J Ok, I see it now. Not sure how I missed it the first time. I still think it's a pretty minor issue. Development tools are not the same as regular applications. Debuggers, profiling, etc all make them stand a little bit to one side.

Comment: @Graymatter I agree it isn't a huge issue, I was just curious about it, and it's slightly annoying that an IDE should be a cause of battery drain when not compiling.

Comment: @J I believe firefox ramps up the timer when it needs to for things like flash and html5 graphics, but is supposed to scale back down when it doesn't need it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The IDE uses a very old version of VirtualTrees.pas for the ProjectManager, StructureView and Log-Window. This version calls `timeBeginPeriod` in its `InitializeGlobalStructures` function and sets the timer resolution to the minimum (1). It is reset in the unit's `finalization` block.

VirtualTrees changed this behavior with this commit:

```
2013-09-20 21:40:21: No longer changing timer resolution globally (#365)
```

But the IDE still uses a very old version that isn't even using UnicodeString but WideString. So it wasn't updated since Delphi 2007.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I guess if I set the timer back after the IDE opens, I might get a little better battery life

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason why Virtual Tree View changed the timer resolution? Would it be safe to just change it back while the IDE is running or could that have adverse effects on the Virtual Tree Views?

Comment: @dummzeuch The code was commented with `Specify an useful timer resolution for timeGetTime`. But only the original author (Mike Lischke) may be able to answer this.